# in Mercurial prevent to up to a older version (tag or branch)

Tags: mercurial, repository

Is there any way to prevent to move back to an older version?

I mean, I want to always do hg up to forward and never to back.

Comment: What's the point of a version control system when the history is unaccessible?

Comment: I am very curious why you would need this limit.

Comment: The point is to prevent devs to deploy older versions or some of them which has not rollback.!

Comment: @FedericoAguirre I would rather use an automated build/deploy process to ensure the correctness of the software

Comment: As outlined in my answer: I build automatically anything pushed to my repo. And a new release build is triggered for any tag pushed to the repo. No manual intervention needed. However: I allow deployment of any tag, old or new, when it is manually triggered (which usually is not needed - but if I do, I might have good reason to do so). I suggest similar system. No option for manual override can prove a bad idea. The usual routine can be savely automated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I also have an automated deployment process! But also I need to handle this scenario! Which is out of the process...! Even when you live in the paradise having all automated, many things works outside the happy path!! ‍♂️. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the [hooks](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Hook) which mercurial offers and implement a hook to the update command which compares the desired version with the currently checked-out version. Fail the hook, when the desired version is older than the currently checked-out one. See the [docs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/hgrc) for the available hooks and some [examples](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HookExamples).

That said, it might be an undesirable constraint on usage of a VCS. If it is about deployment on a production syste, that's more sane; yet then you do not need to copy the whole repository with its history, but just the current version to the deployment target.

For my purpose of deployment, I only check whether the build is set to be a release build (tag, or manually selected in jenkins) or if it is HEAD of a branch. In those cases I trigger the deployment to production after the build passed regression tests: https://github.com/OpenTTD/nml/blob/master/.devzone/build/jenkins_postbuild.sh